# Get JDBC driver from MS to Eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

Trying to add Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server `sqljdbc4.jar` to my eclipse project. I do *Add Library* in *java build path*, select *connectivity driver definition* and have menu below. But there is no driver form MS. How to import `sqljdbc4.jar` to my project?

[image]
UPD:

If I press starburst-thingy with green + as Mark recommends I have menu:
I do select MS SQL server 2014, but button OK is not available. How to to add required lib

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click that starburst-thingy with the green + to the right of that dropdown? BTW: What is wrong with adding it as a normal library?

Comment: After pressing strange button I found MSSQL server, but still can't add lib . More details in UPD question body

Comment: Have you checked the other tabs, maybe you need to add the driver on the _JAR List_ tab before you can really add it. But again, why can't you just add it as a plain jar?

Comment: I don't have JAR, I expect that eclipse will download required jars. By the way, where I can download sqljdbc4.jar and other ones related to it?

Comment: Solved the problem by downloading drivers from MS and adding like external JAR